# Can V8 optimize a function declared async, if all the code in it is synchonous?

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-optimization, v8

The title says it all.
Another way of saying the same thing would be: if an `async function` does not contain any `await` calls does V8 know to optimize it away?

Comment: Optimise *what* away?

Comment: @Bergi optimize the Promise or the await (however v8 internally handles things). So that there's no resources used up for async because the function is treated as sync

Comment: There is no `await` in the function according to your question, what is not there cannot be optimised away. The `Promise` object returned by the async function cannot be optimised away since it still might be used by the caller, and even if ignored by the caller, it still might have to be rejected if there's an exception in the function.

Answer (score 1):

By marking a function `async` you are getting the guarantee that every `return` will end up in a settled Promise being returned and that any thrown exception will end up in a rejected Promise being returned. No matter what tricks the engine could pull, it does not change this fundamental fact.

Also, why would you mark a function as `async` in the first place if you don‘t want to `await` anything? As that does not make sende conceptually, why would engines optimize for it?

The only case where `async` could be omitted entirely is when the function already returns a promise and evaluates no expression that could potentially throw, however unfortunately even then it needs to construct a new promise object:

```js
const prom = Promise.resolve(1);

async function fn1() {
  return prom;
}

function fn2() {
  return prom;
}

console.log(fn1() === prom);
console.log(fn2() === prom);
```